# What's wrong with this ES6 Destructuring array of objects?

Tags: ecmascript-6

I'm trying to create a couple of objects and it works for 2 but not 1.

When there are two objects in the array, it works:

```js
const cars = [{
    model: "Honda Civic",
    colorsByPopularity: ["Red", "Blue"],
    speedStats: {
      topSpeed: 140,
      zeroToSixty: 8.5
    }
  },
  {
    model: "Mitsubishi Outlander",
    colorsByPopularity: ["Gold", "Black"],
    speedStats: {
      topSpeed: 200,
      zeroToSixty: 10.5
    }
  }
]

const [model, {speedStats: {topSpeed, zeroToSixty}}] = cars;
console.log(topSpeed);
console.log(zeroToSixty);
console.log(model);
```

But when there's only a single object in the array, the same pattern doesn't work:

```js
const cars = [{
  model: "Honda Civic",
  colorsByPopularity: ["Red", "Blue"],
  speedStats: {
    topSpeed: 140,
    zeroToSixty: 8.5
  }
}]

const [model, {speedStats: {topSpeed, zeroToSixty}}] = cars;
console.log(zeroToSixty);
```

Because the brackets work, `the console.log` displays the last element. What if I want to display the first element without looping? Changing `topSpeed` to `topSpeed[0]` doesn't work.

Lastly, modifying this and instead of array, just made it an object with collection of objects, but it's throwing an exception `expected to match '}' with '{' but instead saw model.`

```
const cars =  {
brands: {
         {
            model:"Honda Civic",
            colorsByPopularity:["Red","Blue"],
            speedStats: {
                  topSpeed: 140,
                  zeroToSixty: 8.5 }
         },
         {
             model:"Mitsubishi Outlander",
             colorsByPopularity:["Gold","Black"],
             speedStats: {
                   topSpeed: 200,
                   zeroToSixty: 10.5 }
          }
        }
};
```

Comment: Your last example is invalid syntax -- you're conflating an array and an object. Each key has only one value in an object, not multiple. In your first example, you're using array destructuring on two items, `[model, stuffFromSecondIndex]`, so why would you expect that to work on a single-element array?

Comment: in the first example, how is destructuring on 2 items? It's one object,  speedStats has 2 objects inside it.

Comment: The working version is an array with two items: `cars = [/* 2 elements */]; const [model /*from idx 0*/, {/*various stuff from idx 1*/} ] = cars;`. In the "single object" version, that same array destructuring won't work because `{/*various stuff from idx 1*/}` is all trying to pull nested properties from a nonexistent index. A minimal failing example of the pattern would be: `a = [0]; const [x, {y}] = a` which fails because there's no object with property `y` at `a[1]`.

Comment: Maybe show your desired output. I'm not entirely sure what that's supposed to be, I can only explain why the "single object" destructure doesn't work, and why the bottom code is a syntax error.

Comment: I don't really get your explanation. Destructuring is to de-structure the properties of an object to an equivalent property, doesn't need to be 2 or more objects in that array, 1 object will do, or am I missing something here?

Comment: Do you understand the difference between array and object destructuring? Might want to review [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). If you have an array with 1 element, you can only destructure that single element, but you're trying to destructure an element that doesn't exist. I'm not sure how else to explain, sorry :\

Comment: If I understand the difference between those 2 and when to use what, I'm sure I won't be asking questions why my destructuring doesn't work, will I? Look, I appreciate your help, but your explanation is confusing, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Well, sometimes answering a question involves asking whether you understand a more basic sub-pattern within the problem -- I'm trying to simplify/minimize the pattern so it's easier to see the failure. You may be thinking everything within your destructuring assignment applies to only to the first element, when that's not the case due to the array destructuring `[one, two]` syntax. You may think `model` destructures the key `model` from the first element, when it's actually the entire first object. It's a misleading variable name choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example,

```
const [model, {speedStats: {topSpeed, zeroToSixty}} ] = cars;
```

the "array pattern" (`[model, {...}]`) contains two patterns, `model` and `{speedStats: ...}`, which will be applied to the first and second element of the array respectively. I.e. this is equivalent to

```
const model = cars[0];
//                ^^^
const topSpeed = cars[1].speedStats.topSpeed;
//                   ^^^
const zeroToSixty = cars[1].speedStats.topSpeed;
//                      ^^^
```

Since you only have a single element in `cars`, `cars[1]` will return `undefined`, and accessing a property on on `undefined` throws an error.

It seems like you actually want to extract `model`, `topSpeed` and `zeroToSixty` from the *first* element. In that case you have to move the first `{` to make `model` part of the object pattern:

```
const [ {model, speedStats: {topSpeed, zeroToSixty}} ] = cars;
//     ^  <-   ^^
```

Now the array pattern only contains a single pattern (for the first element). It's equivalent to:

```
const model = cars[0].model;
const topSpeed = cars[0].speedStats.topSpeed;
const zeroToSixty = cars[0].speedStats.topSpeed;
```

Comment: Thank you, this is clearer, but why would a single array element became 2 when everything is enclosed in bracket then brace? I'm talking about this single object  const cars =  [
       {
          model:"Honda Civic",
          colorsByPopularity:["Red","Blue"],
          speedStats: {
            topSpeed: 140,
            zeroToSixty: 8.5 }
       }
       ]

Comment: this single object is like written this way in C#:  class SpeedStats { public int topSpeed { get; set; } public double zeroToSixty { get; set;} } class Car { public string model {get; set; } public string[] colorByPopularity {get; set;} public SpeedStats speedStats {get; set;} }  //it's just one class Car with a another class property SpeedStats within it, so I'm just lost why would it be interpreted by javascript as 2 objects in that array?

Comment: *"I'm just lost why would it be interpreted by javascript as 2 objects in that array?"* It's not. The array has only one object. But your *pattern* expects two objects, and that's why the assignment tries to access the first element (which exists) and the second element (which doesn't exist) of the array. And because the second element doesn't exist you are getting an error. Consider this simple example: `const [first,second] = [42];`. `first` will be `42` and `second` will be `undefined` because the array doesn't have a second element.

Comment: Thank you, it's the pattern and the braces that make a lot of difference. Thanks for breaking down the example as well.